# Hide a string using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to hide strings inside a div. Consider the following example where I want to hide "some".

```
<div id="Disappear">Here is some text.</div>
```

After calling the function it should be

```
<div id="Disappear">Here is      text.</div>
```

Notice that the space remains reserved. Also the sentence and string to be hidden are random.

What have I tried?

Replacing the string with spaces. The solution is not elegant, since the width of the spaces can't always be equal to the string.

**UPDATE** I can't use `<span>` either. The actual div contains a lot more strings, using span is not an option.

Comment: Enclose it in a span with the same colour as the background? or do you want it unselectable?

Comment: make the string text color match the background color

Comment: @AlexK. The problem is I can't use span.

Comment: Even inserting one on the fly?

Comment: No, if you want something hidden and still taking space you use the CSS visibility property. Its what its designed for. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-visibility It will not render a box but will still consider it for layout purposes. And I suspect it does what you want better with accessibility considerations too (what if the user is ignoring your choice of colours?).

Comment: I know I will have to use visibility. @AlexK. Is inserting span the only option, I too thought about it but didn't seem quite an elegant solution. Can you show an example?

Comment: If you can't use span, you won't be able to hide text. You may try to replace the word with blank spaces, but the layout may change if you don't use a fixed width font.

Comment: Show us the code you have. It can probably be modified to put the hidden word in a span dynamically rather than replacing with spaces. If you've got that far a bit of extra HTML shouldn't be too hard I'd ahve thought... :)

Comment: Thanks all, paulslater19 example is what I wanted and what you all were suggesting. Its an elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick example - it wraps the search  text in a span, which (through css) changes the visibility to hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/4kTVC/1/

Update  - as mentioned in comments, `{visibility: hidden}` is better than `{color: #fff}`

Comment: this is really nice and simple, great job!

Comment: I am not very good at using Regexs, can you modify it to only hide first matched string?

Comment: @AshwinSingh it's the "g", which means "global search" that was matching all of them. Here is an example with it removed: http://jsfiddle.net/4kTVC/2/